# When 1 px border is added to div, Div size increases, Don't want to do that

Tags: css, html, border

**On click I am adding, 1px border to div, so Div size increases by 2px X 2px. 
I dont want to get div size increased. Is there any simple way to do so?**

**Messy Detailed Explanation**
Actually I am adding DIVs with float:left (same size, like icons) to a container-div, so all stacks up one after another, and when (container-div width is 300px) no space left width-wise so child DIVs comes in next row, so its like catalog, but because of border only selected DIV size get increased, DIV under selected DIV goes to right and creates empty space below selected DIV.

**EDIT:**
Decreasing Height/Width on selection, but how to increase it back. Using some 3rd party framework, so don't have event when DIV loses selection..

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The border css property will increase all elements "outer" size, excepts tds in tables. You can get a visual idea of how this works in Firebug ([discontinued](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_(software))), under the html->layout tab.

Just as an example, a div with a width and height of 10px and a border of 1px, will have an outer width and height of 12px.

For your case, to make it appear like the border is on the "inside" of the div, in your selected CSS class, you can reduce the width and height of the element by double your border size, or you can do the same for the elements padding.

Eg:

```
div.navitem
{
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    /* padding: 5px; */
}

div.navitem .selected
{
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    /* padding: 4px */
}
```

Comment: thnx, i had .dragdrop-selected class but it was used by all dragable objects and I had like 3 different size (3 different type) of Dragable object, so I kept padding same in all 3 AND set padding in .dragdrop-selected.. & it worked. :)

Comment: This is not a good solution for responsive designs. Using `outline` or a border with same color as background (and changing its color to something else when is selected) is more flexible.

Comment: But suppose you need to avoid hard-coding the width, to let the element flow or respond to the view-port width: see my answer using `border-color: transparent`

Comment: No need for these calculations, just set box-sizing to border-box. See [ejfrancis' answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14222863/422845), and see [this article](https://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/).

Comment: Are you sure about the td in tables? In Chrome it still seems to add to the size.

Answer (score 151):

This is also helpful in this scenario. It allows you to set borders without changing div width

```css
textarea { 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

Taken from http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Comment: box-sizing: border-box should really be set on everything as a modern best practice. See https://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in some cases; not exactly sure why. See: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QZaBQG

Comment: @WilsonBiggs Yes! It is not reliable at all!

Comment: yeah browser likes to make the elements bigger when adding border some times even with box sizing set....

Comment: If a width isn't set on the element it ignores box-sizing: border-box.

Answer (score 121):

If you don't have a `border-radius` change `border` to `outline`:

```
outline: 1px solid black;
```

Comment: Works unless you have border-radius.

Comment: `outline-left`, `outline-right`, `outline-top`, `outline-bottom` are really missing....

Comment: if you dont have border-radius then this is the perfect solution.

Comment: This answer just repeats the one given two years earlier by @chowey.

Comment: Works for me even with a `border-radius`

Comment: @71GA what do you mean ?

Comment: As of 2023 this solution works with border radius! It's also a more versatile solution than the current accepted answer as it doesn't affect padding.

Answer (score 97):

Having used many of these solutions, I find using the trick of setting `border-color: transparent` to be the most flexible and widely-supported:

```
.some-element {
    border: solid 1px transparent;
}

.some-element-selected {
    border: solid 1px black;
}
```

Why it's better:

- No need to to hard-code the element's width
- Great cross-browser support (only IE6 missed)
- Unlike with `outline`, you can still specify, e.g., top and bottom borders separately
- Unlike setting border color to be that of the background, you don't need to update this if you change the background, and it's compatible with non-solid colored backgrounds.

Comment: I found this to work best with dynamically sized items in my UX. Stopped the size-shifting happening onMouseOver completely! Thanks Mr. Newell!

Comment: much better than hardcoding a decrease of the width and height for the increase given by a border

Comment: Why isn't this the accepted answer? Simple, effective as well as logical.

Comment: this is a simple yet effective solution.

Comment: Easily the best solution

Comment: It's rare the border that doesn't use border-radius, so outline is not an option for those cases and this is by far the best approach when you want to add a border on focus, select, hover...

Comment: actually there are cases where this is not working so well. for instance when you want to have a 1px border normally and a 2px border on hover or focus. In those cases using pseudo elements with ::after like in Jack Guy's answer works best while still retaining all the upsides of this idea.

Answer (score 71):

set a border on it before you click to be the same color as the background.

Then when you click just change the background color and the width will not change.

Comment: Ingenious! wish I had thought of it myself.

Comment: Yeah, but if you don't have a solid colored background?  See my answer using `border-color: transparent`

Comment: this not gonna work well if you have a shadow box.

Comment: I didn't have the exact same issue, but your answer was helpful for my use case. Thanks

Comment: The best, it works very well, Great solution!Thanks

Answer (score 55):

Another good solution is to use `outline` instead of `border`.  It adds a border without affecting the box model.  This works on IE8+, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari.

(https://stackoverflow.com/a/8319190/2105930)

Comment: It's great, but comparing with border, there is no "outline-left,...", not for my case.

Comment: Then I recommend using `box-shadow` per [my other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671898/outline-on-only-one-border/18841365#18841365) on a similar question. It doesn't have the same browser support, but that is less of an issue these days.

Comment: Thank you #chowey , just realized  `box-shadow` can support one-side border as well, prefect solution.

Comment: `border-color: transparent` has better cross-browser support --- see my answer...

Comment: This comment's under-rated. It's a great way to get a border around an element without resizing it!

Answer (score 40):

I usually use padding to solve this issue. The padding will be added when the border is not there and removed when it is back. Example:

```
.good-border {
  padding: 1px;
}

.good-border:hover {
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

[image]

See my code here: https://jsfiddle.net/3t7vyebt/4/

Comment: Can you tell me what is actually happening , i am confused , why does in bad border hover here shift downwards when you hover over it?

Comment: @SurajJain Because the size of "bad border" div will be changed (add 1px of border) when you hover over it.

Comment: This is a nice trick, thanks!

Answer (score 25):

Try this

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Comment: This should be the answer, dirt simple.

Comment: Why does this not work everywhere? E.g. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QZaBQG

Comment: hi @Tom, I'm not sure why it doesn't work yet. But in your case please consider to remove height in container and use padding instead. Can solve your problem.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes you don't want height or width to be affected without explicitly setting either. In that case, I find it helpful to use pseudo elements.

```
.border-me {
    position: relative;
}

.border-me::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: solid 1px black;
}
```

You can also do a lot more with the pseudo element so this is a pretty powerful pattern.

Comment: I had a 1px border that I wanted to change to 2px, and the only way I could find to do that was by removing the `width` and `height` and adding a `bottom` and `left` property in addition to the `top` and `left`, all of which should be set to the opposite width of the original border (in my case -1px).  Great hack though

Comment: This was quite useful for me actually, and simpler than implementing inner div borders or other hacks.

Answer (score 6):

Just decrease the width and height by double of border-width

Answer (score 6):

You can do some fancy things with inset shadows. Example to put a border on the bottom of an element without changing its size:

```
.bottom-border {
  box-shadow:inset 0px -3px 0px #000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try decreasing the margin size when you increase the border

Answer (score 2):

```
.filter_list_button_remove {
    border: 1px solid transparent; 
    background-color: transparent;
}
.filter_list_button_remove:hover {
    border: 1px solid; 
}
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors,whenn you add some explaination for your intension.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to be able to "border" any element by adding a class and not affect its dimensions. A good solution for me was to use box-shadow. But in some cases the effect was not visible due to other siblings. So I combined both typical box-shadow as well as inset box-shadow. The result is a border look without changing any dimensions.

Values separated by comma. Here's a simple example:

```
.add_border {
    box-shadow:-1px 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), inset -1px 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/91xs47av/)

Adjust for your preferred look and you're good to go!

Answer (score 2):

We can also use css calc() function

```
width: calc(100% - 2px);
```

subtracting 2px for borders

Answer (score 2):

You can try a box-shadow inset

something like this:
box-shadow:inset 0px -5px 0px 0px  #fff

adds a white 5px border to the bottom of the element without increasing the size

Answer (score 1):

You can create the element with border with the same color of your background,
then when you want the border to show, just change its color.

Comment: Yeah, but suppose your background isn't a solid color... see my response based on using `border-color: transparent`

Comment: Or all together like `ul li a{border-bottom:2px solid transparent;} ul li a:hover{border-bottom:2px solid red;}`

Answer (score 0):

In case content of your `div` is rendered dynamically and you want to set its height, you can use a simple trick with `outline`:

```
button {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 4px solid blue;
    border-radius: 4px;
    outline: 2px solid white;
    outline-offset: -4px;
}

button:hover {
    outline-color: transparent;
}
```

Example here: https://codepen.io/Happysk/pen/zeQzaZ

Comment: The outline doesn't have rounded corners unfortunately :(