# Re sizing list items gracefully

Tags: jquery, css

I have a list of products composed of two columns of inline-block list items. I would like the user to be able to click these items and have them expand to display more information, but it is not rendering as i would like.

I am using simple class toggles to increase the width of items :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#products').on('click', 'li', function () {
$(this).toggleClass("open")
});
});
```

Expanding an item on the left fills the space and bumps the whole lot down as i would like. But expanding an item in the right column brings that item down and leaves a gap.

Here is the whole thing:

http://jsfiddle.net/MHJDB/

Is there a better way to build this list to have items cascade naturally when they change size?

Comment: I am not sure whats the problem. Your fiddle looks proper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a jQuery based solution that I've come up with.

Not the perfect one but will help you to get started.

jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MHJDB/3/)

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#products').on('click', 'li', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("open");

          if("open" === $(this).attr("class")) {
            if($(this).before())
              $(this).before($(this).next());
              else
              $(this).after($(this));
        }

        if("right" === $(this).css("float") ) {
        $(this).after($(this).prev());
    }      
    });
    });
```

In the code above, it swipes the position of elements if the clicked element is on the right side.

Hope it helps! :-)

Comment: This looks like a good solution, i had no idea you could perform sinmple reordering with .before and .after

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is you're using `border` property for each `li`.

On checking this [**SO answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3254745/1671639):

> **The border css property will increase all elements "outer" size**,
>   excepts tds in tables.
>
> Just as an example, a *div with a width and height of 10px and a border
>   of 1px*, will have an ***outer width and height of 12px***.

So I would suggest to replace your

```
border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
```

with [**outline**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline)

```
outline: 1px solid #eeeeee;
```

> Outlines differ from borders in the following ways:
>
> - ***Outlines do not take up space, they are drawn above the content.*** [for you]
> - Outlines may be non-rectangular.

Add with that,

`margin: 5px` Set all the four margins of an element:

```
#products li {
    margin: 5px;
}
```

so Instead have

```
#products li {
     margin-bottom: 5px;  // equivalent to margin: 0px 0px 5px; 0px;
    }
```

Check this [**Updated JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MHJDB/2/)