# How do I add a border to an clickable element without disturbing the content?

Tags: html, css

**Hello, I wanted to create a border for an element when it's hovered.**

Example (from nsw.gov.au):
[image: Unclciked Version]

Not yet clicked.
[image: Clicked Version]

Hovering/clicked.

**However, when I tried to add that to my website using:**

```
.btn:hover {
    border: 2px solid #022714 !important;
}
```

It distributed the content within it:
[image]
[image]

**Extra:**
I would also like the border not to be directly outside an element, but to have a border 2px outside the element (I hope that make sense).

[image]

> I've tried answers from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254587/when-1-px-border-is-added-to-div-div-size-increases-dont-want-to-do-that) but it does not fix my problems + create new ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a combination of different answers to achieve what I want.

I add another `<div>` BEFORE the element div (including ones that have CSS shadow) and added `margin: 2px` (this is for border being 2px outside the element).

Within that div, I also added the `clickables` CSS class. Then I add to CSS:

```
.clickables {
    border: 2px solid transparent !important;
}

.clickables:hover {
    border: 2px solid #022714 !important;
}
```

(you might need to its own div for clickables, have this BEFORE the margin div; should there be any problems)

You don't need to have any kind of hardcoded margin/top/bottom using this.

Results:
[image: Working]
[image: Working]

Answer (score 0):

You need to encapsulate the inner elements of that button/card, as the example below, I use `div.container`:

```css
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.card:hover {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 3px;
}

.container {
  padding: 15px 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b>John Doe</b></h4>
    <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Set the hover for outer element (`.card`) and put the padding into it. Then just let the inner element as it used to be.

If you don't want it to have "movement", just set the border thickness and the padding for the `.card:hover` so if it adds up altogether, it will be the same as the padding of `.card`.

Comment: On the snippet, it still seems to be moving.

Comment: @P.Z. Already added the math strategy for border and padding to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `border` in the background colour, Then change it color when `:hover`

```css
row{ display:inline-flex; }
button{
  border: 4px solid green;
  background: green;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding: 10px;
  color:white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
button:hover{
  border: 4px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class=row>
  <button>Home</button>
  <button>About</button>
  <button>Contact</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a pseudo element on hovering which has absolute positioning relative to its 'button' so does not disturb other layout.

Also, it can be sized to be larger than the li element itself so you can get the gap you'd like.

[image]

Here's a simple example:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: inline-box;
  width: auto;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  margin: 15px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

li:hover::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 7px;
  /* 2px more than the li element */
  border: solid black 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  top: -9px;
  left: -9px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>HOME</li>
  <li>ARTICLES</li>
  <li>QUIZ</li>
  <li>ABOUT</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set transparent border for that element and on hover make it colored

Comment: This for some reason blocks the shadows.

Answer (score 0):

I used `display: flex;` with `justify-content: center;` and `flex-wrap: wrap;` to make the elements wrap when the screen gets smaller. Then I created the boxes with invisible borders and made the borders visible when hovering over the boxes.

Here is the code:

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px -2px silver;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #315A9A;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
  border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0); /* Invisible Border */
  transition: all 0.2s;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 15px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.box::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 202px;
  height: 102px;
  padding: 9px;
  border: solid rgba(0,0,0,0) 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  top: -7px;
  left: -7px;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.15s;
}

.box:hover::before {
  border: solid #3982AF 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="box">2021 Covid-19 Support Package</div>
  <div class="box">2021 Covid-19 Support Package</div>
  <div class="box">2021 Covid-19 Support Package</div>
  <div class="box">2021 Covid-19 Support Package</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any way to do the extra (I would also like the border not to be directly outside an element, but to have a border 2px outside the element)?

Comment: @P.Z. Let me know if you want to change anything

Answer (score -1):

Try adding an overflow hidden along with other properties. Refer here:  https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=css-add-border-on-mouse-hover-without-affecting-the-surrounding-elements